# How to use ajax to run php file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When a facebook comment is posted I would like to use ajax to trigger a php code to send an email. The php email code is working. And the facebook code is working. I'm stuck on the ajax. My code is:

```
FB.Event.subscribe("comment.create", function() {
$.ajax({type: "POST",
url: "//thesite.com/mail.php", 

    success: function() {
            alert("Request Sent.");
         }
    });
```

I have a console error: TypeError: $.ajax is not a function 
What is wrong with my ajax code? I need to run the mail.php file.

Comment: Did you have include jQuery in your page?

Answer (score 4):

If `$.ajax()` is not a function then that means when this code runs the jQuery library hasn't been loaded into the DOM.  You need to include it before running any jQuery code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is often included in the header of the HTML document.  Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Page content
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And the `$.ajax` should be wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: @AmazingDreams: Why?  It doesn't rely on anything in the DOM.  It should be triggered by _something_, most likely.  But waiting for the DOM to be ready likely isn't it.

Comment: Nope, you are right. Never mind.

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis etc... if you're not testing on server...

Comment: I've added the code and I still (only sometimes) get the error on line 37 of https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.iw.QaH1NQKzkhQ.O/m=plusone/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=EQ/rs=AItRSTO9yyzTauP8Nv5p2FYXcPU2RmiaXQ/cb=gapi.loaded_0 even when there is no error the ajax code doesn't work...

Comment: @LTech: What error do you get from the Google API?  I don't recognize that link in your comment.  When you reference the jQuery library, in what way does the AJAX code "not work"?